# Keeping TempData for "just one more request..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, items in `TempData` are maintained in the session until they are read, after which they expire at the end of the current request.

This has the side-effect that refreshing a page using `TempData` will lose that data. In some situations (e.g. alerts), that's fine. In others (e.g. confirmation screens with cached view models) it's not. I have a confirmation screen which retrieves a model from `TempData` from the previous post:

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
{
    var model = TempData["model"];
    return View(model);
}
```

Pressing F5 breaks the confirmation screen. Now, I know I can keep hold of my `TempData` objects with either of the following, fixing the issue:

```
// Peek
var model = TempData.Peek("model");

// Keep
var model = TempData["model"];
TempData.Keep("model");
```

However, because the model is not read from `TempData` again after the next post, the cached model is now never removed (except in the normal circumstances in which a session variable is removed), negating the benefit of `TempData`.

Is there a way I can get a `TempData` key to persist for "just one more request," or am I limited to simply using `Session` and explicitly removing the key in the next request?

Answer (score 1):

Tempdata is made to keep state **across a redirect**. Hitting F5 is not a redirect, it's a page refresh, so yes, your data will be lost. So don't try to use TempDate for this purpose.

Alternatives:

- Use output caching to cache your confirmation page on the client.
- Use Cache to temporarily cache the page's data.
- Store parameters as part of the URL.
- Cookies

I would avoid the use of session anyway.

Note: don't forget to apply the POST - redirect - GET pattern after the confirmation!

Comment: You might be right - maybe I am abusing `TempData` here. I'm opting for the use of session in this instance as it's the simplest way to uphold PRG and also rich confirmation screens available (and the risk of data loss is an acceptable trade-off for simplicity in this case). I might switch to cookies, though, and introduce generated keys to prevent conflicts between concurrent page views in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

I liked your technique to retain data in `TempData` between multiple HTTP requests. `TempData` is a dictionary object derived from `TempDataDictionary`. Unfortunately there is no way that you can retain its value after reading once and its name signifies that. The value stored in `TempData` stays only for a subsequest HTTP request that reads data stored in it.

However, one good thing about `TempData` is it can be used to pass data between controllers, which can not be done through `ViewBag` or `ViewData`. To answer your question, Yes, there is no way to persist data for 'just one more request' in `TempData`.

You may have to use a round about or try `ViewBag`, `ViewData` or `Session`.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct (I'm also not sure you have fully understood my question). As I mentioned in my question, `TempData` keys do not just persist for one request - they persist until the request in which they are read. And there certainly *are* ways of retaining `TempData` values after they are read (my question demonstrates two!).

Comment: Hi Ant P. Yes, I agree. What I meant by subsequent HTTP request is the request that reads the values from 'TempData' and I meant that there is no direct way of retaining data. What ever we can try are only round abouts to mimic our requirements.